# Angular 8 custom form builder

Tags: javascript, angular

I have problem creating a custom Angular form. When using this function, customer is able to create dynamic form which allow to drag drop custom input/label/textbox... with grid system (like bootstrap) to the form and save the input data to html or xml. Anyone has solution or demo code for this issue? Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Your code doesn't show any attempts on your side to solve the issue, it would be great if you add code to your question so we better understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @AsimHashmi sorry, i'm trying to archive function like wordpress form, please refer to short introduction here:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=22&v=eiQ3viAGung